# Change Dropbox computer name

Tags: dropbox

I have a Dropbox account installed on two machines - both Mac Minis, the users of these machines both have their own users accounts on the machines, but each machine is configured and managed from an admin account on the respective computers this account is called Admin.

When there is a conflicting file saved in Dropbox both machines are described as 'admin's mac mini'. Even though the users created the file on on their own seperate system user account. Is there a way to change the name Dropbox has for each computer, to get a more descriptive computer name such as 'John's Mac Mini' ?

Comment: Thanks to ale for opening a bounty! This answer https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91887/166659 is outdated. It is not possible to double click on the names anymore. I tried with several browsers and logging in with the app and over the website. I also dont know if it is a bug or somehow purpusefully implemented to sell more copies of the team version.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to edit computer names in Dropbox.

1. Go to Dropbox.com and log in.
2. Click your name in the upper right, and click Settings in the dropdown menu.
3. Click the Security tab near the top of the page.
4. Scroll down to where it says "Devices". This is a list of all your connected computers and phones and whatnot.
5. Double click the name of the computer you want to rename, type the new name, and click Save.

That's it!

Comment: That does not work as of 2021-09-29.  The text of the computer name can be selected but the name cannot be modified.